# Calculate proper rate within CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
    Existing Tables:

    Projects
    - projectID
    - name
    - rate

    Shifts
    - shiftID (PK)
    - projectID (FK)
    - name
    - startTime
    - rate

    [Shifts]
    ID  projectID   userID  shift     startTime                 baseRate    addition
    1   1           1       Shift A   1900-01-01 08:00:00.000   15.00       10%
    1   1           1       Shift B   1900-01-01 17:00:00.000   15.00       2

    [Projects]
    ID  project     rate
    1   Project A   10
```

Logic: shift rate consists of two fields ( baserate + addition ) where [addition] can be either a percent or a fixed dollar amount. I have a SELECT query to determine the proper rate that needs to be applied, but there is a bug:

**when the [addition] is a fixed dollar amount, the base rate multiplies the addition instead of adding it**

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.rate,0) = 0 THEN p.rate ELSE s.rate END * 
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%',s.addition)>0 
                THEN (1+CAST(REPLACE(s.addition,'%','') AS FLOAT)/100) 
                ELSE 1+CAST(ISNULL(s.addition,0) AS FLOAT) 
            END
        AS finalRate
    FROM Projects p 
    INNER JOIN Shifts s ON p.ID = s.projectID
```

So, I need to fix this line **ELSE 1+CAST(ISNULL(sw.addition,0) AS FLOAT) **

Please note that the query snippet is part of a much larger query, so it cannot be changed too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
ELSE 1+CAST(ISNULL(s.addition,0) AS FLOAT)
```

to:

```
ELSE (CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.rate,0) = 0 THEN p.rate ELSE s.rate END + 
CAST(ISNULL(s.addition,0) AS FLOAT)) / CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.rate,0) = 0 THEN p.rate ELSE s.rate END
```

Based on formula:

if you have 15 as rate and 2 as addition, you want to get 17 with multiplication. So, by what number you should multiply 15 to get 17?

```
15 * x = 15 + 2
x = (15 + 2) / 15
```

Another option will be changing the order of case statements:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%',s.addition)>0 
            THEN CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.rate,0) = 0 THEN p.rate ELSE s.rate END * (1+CAST(REPLACE(s.addition,'%','') AS FLOAT)/100) 
            ELSE CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.rate,0) = 0 THEN p.rate ELSE s.rate END + CAST(ISNULL(s.addition,0) AS FLOAT) 
        END
    AS finalRate
FROM Projects p 
INNER JOIN Shifts s ON p.ID = s.projectID
```

Comment: when baseRate is 15 and [addition] is 2, then we do **baseRate + [addition]**

Comment: When you will multiply 15 on (15 + 2)/15 you will get 15 + 2. This is the idea

Comment: when baseRate is 15 and [addition] is 2, then we do **baseRate + [addition]**, when [addition] is 10%, then we do **baseRate * (1+[addition]/100)**

Comment: I understand. Did you check solution? It should work